# XAML designer in visual studio cannot display anything

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2012

Why is it that every time I open a user control or anything a little more complicated than simple markup, Visual studio is unable to display it in the designer? Sometimes I have a form where there are several elements, but all the designer displays is a rectangle? How does one work on more complicated pages with XAML?

Comment: Generally speaking, the designer will break like that if your markup isn't correct (just because it runs doesn't make it correct.) You might share an example of the troubled code. Included to that though, Blend is great for working in XAML, though the intellisense isn't as good as in VS, but it does make XAML work generally easier.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `Binding` in XAML, VS designer invokes the binded object as a compiled manner like part of your program being executed. At this time, if the binded object does not prepare any fake data programatically which gives `null` in general, VS designer is failed to render UI because it is treated as `NullReferenceException` during rendering process.

Those fake data is called **design-time data** in XAML.
To prepare design-time fake data for UI, please check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11561369/361100

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, Visual Studio's designer is almost completely useless for anything more complicated than the simplest designs.  Have you tried using Blend?  It actually works (most of the time.)

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio Professional 2013. Does Blend come with it or is this a separate purchase?

Comment: Yes, from what I understand it comes with it.  I'm currently using 2010 and it was as separate purchase, but other co-workers have 2013 and they've been using Blend.

Comment: "Blend is installed when you install Visual Studio. To locate Blend, type Blend in the Search box."  This comes from "Getting started with Blend for Visual Studio 2013" at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj171012.aspx.