# Visual Studio doesn't show the Visual Designer for a Popup anymore

Tags: wpf, visual-studio

So in the past when I clicked on the XAML on a Popup, Visual Studio would show me the Visual layout of the Popup's contents. And I could move elements around just like a normal Window.

I can no longer get this to happen. It was about 5 years since I tried and last time I was using Framework and a different version of Visual Studio.

I'm on Visual Studio 2022, using .NET 6.

Is this no longer supported or am I missing something? In the past if I recall correctly your popup had to have a Height and Width for it to appear in the visual designer, but after trying it, that doesn't work.

I've tried Blend as well with no luck. No options on the Right-Click menu.

I can edit by hand but that takes so much longer than using a visual editor for positioning.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean you are missing the design window? If so you can find it under the window options at the top bar.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22560477/16764901 Did this answer help you?

Comment: @Gretl0ng The designer shows for the window, but when I select the Popup, it does not show up. It used to at one point so I could visually edit the contents of the Popup.

Comment: @Jiale Xue I've tried opening in Blend as well but it still doesn't show the designer for the popup. I've tried rebuilding the project, opening and closing VS and Blend etc, no luck. I've tried changing the target of the popup in the event it was that but that also didn't work.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jQwh.png Is this what you mean?

Comment: I mean to be able to see it in that part of the window yes. In the past you used to be able to do it. There is still an option in the Document Outline sidebar. If you rightclick on your popup you can select an option to show the contents of the popup. Currently it does nothing though.

Comment: I can confirm this. Visual Studio 2017 shows the contents of a popup if you click inside the <popup>-node in XAML editor. Visual 2022 does not :-(

Comment: Please have a look here, it is broken for VS2022 https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/unable-to-preview-popup-in-the-wpf-design-mode-1/1519040

Comment: Thanks for the link. Sorry to see the issue is stuck in the backlog and may never be fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this no longer supported or am I missing something?

You are correct, this used to work in Visual Studio 2019 but is no longer supported/implemented in Visual Studio 2022.

Microsoft have said as much [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/unable-to-preview-popup-in-the-wpf-design-mode-1/1519040#T-N1553372), and said they have no plan to fix it.

Comment: Unfortunate but true.